# What is the indicator char '?' and after it in URI?

Tags: android, url, url-scheme

I want to know in URI character '`?`' and after it what thing define?

For example in `market://details?id=com.mobiliha.badesaba`

char '`?`' and after it What is the indicator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It demarcates variables from URI in HTTP GET requests. In HTTP protocol, you can use the GET method to request resources from a server. You can pass variables to the server in your request. The "?" indicates that the URI part is over and variables have begun.

In your example, `id` is a variable with the value `com.mobiliha.badesaba` that is passed to the URI in question. The URI `market://details` specifies a URI scheme that the play store app will have registered itself for. This means that when this URI is fired by the system, the play store app can receive it, extract the 'id' variable and do what it needs to do.

More info about HTTP GET and POST methods here:
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp

Comment: thnx . but in android app when i call an other app , what it determines ?